# No implicit reference conversion when attempting to use generic extension method

Tags: c#, generics, constraints, extension-methods

Even having browsed stack overflow for similar answers I'm struggling to understand the concepts behind why I'm experiencing issues.

**My code is below:**

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        HomePage page = new HomePage();
        page.Load(); //No Error
        LoginPage page2 = new LoginPage();
        page2.Load(); //No Error
        ApprenticePage page3 = new ApprenticePage();
        page3.Load(); //No implicit reference conversion
        ApprenticeEPA page4 = new ApprenticeEPA();
        page4.Load(); //No implicit reference conversion
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public abstract class BasePage<T> where T : BasePage<T> {
    public abstract bool EvaluateLoad();
}

public class HomePage : BasePage<HomePage>
{
    public override bool EvaluateLoad()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In HomePage");
        return true;
    } 
}

public class LoginPage : BasePage<LoginPage>
{
    public override bool EvaluateLoad()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In LoginPage");
        return true;
    }
}

public class ApprenticePage : HomePage
{
    public override bool EvaluateLoad()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In ApprenticePage");
        return false;
    }
}

public class ApprenticeEPA : ApprenticePage
{
    public override bool EvaluateLoad()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In ApprenticeEPA");
        return false;
    }
}

public static class Helper {
    public static T Load<T>(this T page) where T : BasePage<T> {
        if (page.EvaluateLoad()) {
            Console.WriteLine("It's true!");
            return page;
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine("It's false!");
            return default(T);
        }        
    }
}
```

**I'm getting the following error:**

> The type 'IndexerTest.ApprenticePage' cannot be used as type parameter
>   'T' in the generic type or method 'Helper.Load(T)'. There is no
>   implicit reference conversion from 'IndexerTest.ApprenticePage' to
>   'IndexerTest.BasePage<IndexerTest.ApprenticePage>'.

In my mind, as `ApprenticePage` inherits from `HomePage`, which inherits from `BasePage<T>`, using the load method would be okay but obviously it isn't.

How would I fix my `Load` method so that it could be called on all instances of the classes in my code with that classes specific implementation of `EvaluateLoad()`?

Comment: According to constraint on the extension method `where T : BasePage<T> `,  when T is `ApprenticePage`, `ApprenticePage` is not `BasePage<ApprenticePage>` hence the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you examine the error closely, it says the following:

> There is no implicit reference conversion from 'ApprenticePage' to 'BasePage<ApprenticePage>'

This is correct; `ApprenticePage` is a `BasePage<HomePage>`, it's not a `BasePage<ApprenticePage>`

What you're trying to do is create an extension method which works on anything that implements `BaseType<T>`. So, your extension method should look like this:

```
public static BasePage<T> Load<T>(this BasePage<T> page) where T : BasePage<T>
{
    if (page.EvaluateLoad())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("It's true!");
        return page;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("It's false!");
        return null; // No need for default() here - default() of a reference type is
                     // always going to be null
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. If I were to have a method on `LoginPage` called `LoginClick` and a method on `ApprenticeEPA` page called `EPAClick`, is it possible to create a Load<T> extension method that would allow me to do both `loginPage.Load().LoginClick()` and `apprenticeEPAPage.Load().EPAClick()`? I'm not sure this is possible as the constraint would need to be for both `BasePage<HomePage>` and `BasePage<LoginPage>`. Thanks

Comment: @Konzy262 In that case just have it as `Load(this LoginPage page)`